# Galeria de imagens css na forma de lista (limitar e centralizar as imagens na tela)

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

Olá, tenho uma pagina onde quero organizar as imagens na forma de listas acho que o exemplo vai explica melhor, mas a ideia é organizar as imagens de 3 ou 4 por linha (espaço) e com margem na direita e na esquerda de 5vh! Obrigado

```
<section class="produtos"><ul><li><img src="img/exemplo.jpg" alt="produto</li><li><img src="img/exemplo.jpg" alt="produto"></li><li><img src="img/exemplo.jpg" alt="produto"></li><li><img src="img/exemplo.jpg" alt="produto"></li><li><img src="img/exemplo.jpg" alt="produto"></li><li><img src="img/exemplo.jpg" alt="produto"></li></ul></section>
```

Answer (score 1):

VH (viewport height) é usado para altura, sendo assim não recomendo vc usar como margem na largura...

De qualquer maneira, fiz das 2 formas.
Usando vh na margem:
https://jsfiddle.net/tkedrLe2/1/

```css
.produtos ul li {
  width: 23.333vh;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 5vh;
}
```

```html
<section class="produtos">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img src="img/exemplo.jpg" alt="produto">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="img/exemplo.jpg" alt="produto">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="img/exemplo.jpg" alt="produto">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="img/exemplo.jpg" alt="produto">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="img/exemplo.jpg" alt="produto">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="img/exemplo.jpg" alt="produto">
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

---

Maneira mais correta:
https://jsfiddle.net/tkedrLe2/

```css
.produtos ul li{
  width: 33.333%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<section class="produtos">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img src="img/exemplo.jpg" alt="produto">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="img/exemplo.jpg" alt="produto">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="img/exemplo.jpg" alt="produto">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="img/exemplo.jpg" alt="produto">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="img/exemplo.jpg" alt="produto">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="img/exemplo.jpg" alt="produto">
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```